# What is the equivalent of this tradition for loop to a for each loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I have a tradition for loop below and I just wondering what the equivalent loop would be for each loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
{
    words.set(i, words.get(i).toUpperCase());
}
```

In addition, for those, who are wondering, words is an arrayList of type String.

Comment: you are using arraylists , foreach doesn't work for the code written above ...

Comment: in other words nothing happens

Comment: So, you can't use a for each loop for an arrayList only for an array

Comment: see my answer , i described it

Comment: [Nice code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41863886/2970947). `String` is **immutable**. And you can't modify the reference because the [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) hides the `Iterator`. As noted in the for-each loop link, *Similarly it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Wow even a different OP

Comment: I can't help thinking that if OP had copied the code from Elliott's earlier answer, the left curly wouldn't have migrated to the line below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the bugs in the following method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863821/what-are-the-bugs-in-the-following-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for-each construct doesn't allow you to set an element. This because the syntactic sugar it provides hides the `Iterator<E>` completely.

```
for (String word : words)
 ...
```

is equivalent to

```
for (Iterator<String> it = words.iterator(); it.hasNext(); /**/) {
  String word = it.next();
  ...
}
```

This could work if `String` instances were mutable object such that you can modify the content without modifying the reference but that's not the case. To be able to do what you need with a for-each you'd need a wrapper class, eg:

```
List<AtomicReference<String>> words = ...;
for (AtomicReference<String> word : words)
  word.set(word.get().toUpperCase());
```

Comment: there is a semicolon missing in your second code , if `for` loop

Answer (score 3):

The `for` loop with indexes is fine, but just so you know, you can also use a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which allows replacing of the current item via `set`:

```
for (ListIterator<String> iterator = words.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  String word = iterator.next();
  iterator.set(word.toUpperCase());
}
```

Which is not an enhanced for-loop, but is very close to what an enhanced for loop actually is with non-array `Iterable`s.

Comment: This isn't a for-each loop, as asked for by OP, but it's a more efficient basic for loop (e.g. for `LinkedList`). +1.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would be interested in the java 8 way of doing this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Class {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("hello");
    words = words.stream()
      .map(String::toUpperCase)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(words);
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent, though: the basic for loop above is doing the uppercasing without allocating a new list. (It's still allocating new strings, though, obvs).

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that nobody has pointed out the following structure, using an enhanced for loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (String str : words) {
  words.set(i++, str.toUpperCase());
}
```

Now, this is pretty gross, and inefficient unless `words` is an instance of `RandomAccess`; I'd much prefer to use the [`ListIterator` approach proposed by Weston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41865340/3788176).

This works for `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` etc without a `ConcurrentModificationException` because that is only thrown following [*structural modification* of the list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.

Note that there is no safe approach for a general `List` implementation (including the basic for loop in the original question): `set` is an optional operation, and you can't tell if it is implemented for a `List` without trying it.

Comment: I guess that noone pointed out that solution because it's really fragile and forces you to make many assuptions on the underlying implementation (which is always bad in object oriented programming). Actually a better solution would be just to use stream and collect the result: `list = list.stream().map(s -> s.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList())`. Maybe slower (maybe not since of parallelisation fully applicable here) but surely safer and readable.